# Alternative to call_user_func_array

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I have to use `call_user_func_array()` in my PHP script. It seems terribly slow though. Are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: Show the context of how you're using it.

Comment: Do the arguments need to be in an array, or will `call_user_func()` suffice?

Comment: "It seems terribly slow though" - how did you measure that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in performance when using `call_user_func_array` vs. calling the function directly, but it's not that big (around 15x slower). Unless you're using it thousands of times, you won't notice it.

To answer your question, you can build one yourself:

```
function call($fn, array $args = array()){

  $numArgs = count($args);

  if($numArgs < 1)
    return $fn();

  if($numArgs === 1)  
    return $fn($args[0]);

  if($numArgs === 2)  
    return $fn($args[0], $args[1]);

  // ...

  return call_user_func_array($fn, $args);
}
```

There's also [`ReflectionFunction::invokeArgs`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.invokeargs.php) (and [`ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php)):

```
$reflector = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
return $reflector->invokeArgs($args);
```

Another solution (probably the best one) is to make your functions accept an array with the arguments...

Comment: One should not that the `ReflectionFunction` is slower than `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: I have a similar function that I use that uses `switch( count($args) )` in a trait, and handles up to 14 parameters before finally defaulting to `call_user_func_array` as the default. It's benchmarked quite a lot faster than `call_user_func_array` and also significantly faster than using reflectors. I don't think I've ever seen it hit the default. It would have to be an absurdly unusable function to ever get that far.

Comment: @mopsyd: nice approach!